# Verficar se número digitado realmente é inteiro no Visualg

Tags: visualg, pseudocódigo

Eu não estou conseguindo colocar a lógica do  num % 1 = 0 que vi pela internet haha
Sou novo nesse mundo rs

Algoritmo "semnome"
// Data atual  : 06/10/2021
Var

num, a : inteiro

Inicio

leia (num)
a <- num % 1
se (a = 0) entao
escreva("número inteiro")
senao
escreval("erro / número real")
fimse

Fimalgoritmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o manual do visualg 3.0 a função `Caracpnum()` recebe um caractere e retorna o valor em inteiro ou em real.
Para mais informações segue o [link do manual](http://manual.visualg3.com.br/doku.php?id=manual) do visualG 3.0